# How to set display margins for markdown-mode buffers?

Tags: hooks, display, markdown-mode, margins

Is there a way to set the display margins for `markdown-mode` buffers? I've read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Margins.html and various suggested solutions but nothing has worked for me. This is what I have currently:

```
(defun my-margins ()
  (set-window-margins (selected-window) 30 30))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'my-margins)
```

However, nothing happens when I open a `.md` file. If I evaluate `(my-margins)` manually, however, then I get the desired result, until I switch to a different buffer, and then the margins are lost.

Ideally, I would like all `markdown-mode` buffers to have the desired display margins, regardless of whether I open a new frame, switch buffers, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to center the text in the window ?

Comment: @TristanRiehs Yes, that's my intention. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, the `visual-fill-column-center-text` feature from [visual-fill-column](https://github.com/joostkremers/visual-fill-column) allows you to do it very easily. @jth

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `my-margins` function you provided using `markdown-mode-hook`, `selected-window` does not return the window you expect. For example, if you call `find-file test.md` from the `*scratch*` buffer, `selected-window` will return the window displaying the `*scratch*` buffer, not the new one displaying the buffer of `test.md`.

To make your function work, you can call it from another hook, one where in the previous example `selected-window` would return the window displaying the markdown file. You can use `window-configuration-change-hook`.

We have to adapt `my-margins` since this hook is not only fired in `markdown-mode` :

```
(defun markdown-margins ()
  (when (equal major-mode 'markdown-mode)
    (set-window-margins (selected-window) 30 30)))

(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'my-margins)
```